# how can i fix this error update problem flutter dart

Tags: flutter, dart, sdk

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/khfci.png)

can you solve the problem? I made a flutter update. I got this error. I understood that there was an error path, but I did not understand how to fix it.

I don't know how to fix I'm new in this.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have some invalid path in your Windows system/user paths. Try to follow these steps from documentation to properly add Flutter to you path (it may be already there) and remove invalid Dart path (you need to look for it on your own):

https://docs.flutter.dev/get-started/install/windows#update-your-path

https://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm

Answer (score -1):

No need to download dart sdk saperately
If added then remove c:\users\elmob\downloads\dart-sdk\bin... path from environment variables.
Add these path to your environment variable.

C:\src\flutter\bin
C:\src\flutter\bin\cache\dart-sdk

*Happy Coding :)*